# Does $\sin(x+iy) = x+iy$ have infinitely many solutions?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

How to prove that $\sin(x+iy) = x+iy$ has infinitely many solutions? I know how to prove that $\sin(x) = x$ has only one solution, but I do not know how to extend this to complex analysis.

Comment: Maybe it works trying to express $sin(x+iy)$ in binomial form and equating real and imaginary parts. Probably one of the equations has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Maybe [Weierstrass Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) can help.

Comment: The sine function maps any infinite strip of the form $\{x+iy:2n\pi\leq x \leq 2(n+1)\pi\}$ onto the entire complex plane. As a result, I believe it must have a fixed point in that strip.

Comment: @MarkMcClure If so (and I 'feel like' that should be true), this is special to holomorphic functions or the sine function; there are homeomorphisms from that strip to the plane that don't have a fixed point.

Comment: @MikeMiller True.  Here is a simpler statement that should yield the result: For sufficiently large $M$, the image of the rectangle $R=\{x+iy: 2n\pi \leq x \leq 2(n+1)\pi \text{ and } -M \leq y \leq M\}$ under the sine function contains $R$.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Yes, I agree that does it. I think you should expand on it and post it as an answer. :)

Comment: @MikeMiller Will do a little later. While I upvoted your answer, I like the fact that mine yields information on the location of the fixed points.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I prefer yours to mine for that reason and the fact that it doesn't require big tools. Thanks (in advance) for the answer.

Comment: @MikeMiller Done!

Comment: I love the variety of answers here!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [great Picard theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) says that $f(z) = \sin(z)-z = c \in \Bbb C$ infinitely often for all but possibly one value of $c$. Note that $f(z+2\pi) = f(z) - 2\pi$. Suppose some $c_0$ is not hit infinitely many times; then $c_0+2\pi$ is, say $f(z_k) = c_0+2\pi$ for some infinite sequence $(z_k)$. By the above functional equation, then, $f(z_k+2\pi) = c_0$, providing an infinite sequence that maps to $c_0$. So $f^{-1}(c)$ is infinite for every $c \in \Bbb C$; in particular, this is the case for $c=0$ as desired.

Note that the same argument shows that for any holomorphic function $g$ with a sort of periodicity (i.e., there's some $c, d \in \Bbb C$ such that for all $z \in \Bbb C$, $g(z+c) = g(z)+d$), $g^{-1}(z)$ is infinite for any $z \in \Bbb C$. (The great Picard theorem demands that $g$ not be polynomial; but the above periodicity phenomenon precludes this from being possible, lest it have infinitely many roots.)

Comment: Note that in your generalization at the end, you need $d\neq 0$ (in the first paragraph, that corresponds to the fact that $c_0$ and $c_0+2\pi$ are different so that $c_0+2\pi$ is hit infinitely many times).  Of course, if you allow $d=0$, then you could have $g(z)=e^z$ which is never $0$.

Answer (score 9):

Following is an elementary and mundane approach which count/bound the roots of the equation
$$\sin z = z\tag{*1}$$ 
using [winding number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number).
For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $r > 0$, let

- $R_n = (2n+\frac32)\pi$,
- $C_n$ be the square contour centered at origin with side $2R_n$.
- $S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4$ be the following $4$ line segments whose union is $C_n$.
  $$\begin{cases}
  S_1 &= [ -R_n - R_ni, +R_n - R_ni ]\\
  S_2 &= [ +R_n - R_ni, +R_n + R_ni ]\\
  S_3 &= [ +R_n + R_ni, -R_n + R_ni ]\\
  S_4 &= [ -R_n + R_ni, -R_n - R_ni ]
  \end{cases}$$
- $\Delta_{S_i}$ be the charge of $\;\arg(\sin z - z)\;$ as we move $z = x + iy$ along 
  the segment $S_i$ counter-clockwisely with respect to the origin.
- $\mathcal{W}_n$ be the winding number of the image of $\sin z - z$ with respect to the origin as $z$ move along $C_n$ once. By definition, it is equal to
  $$\mathcal{W}_n \stackrel{def}{=}\frac{\Delta_{S_1} + \Delta_{S_2} + \Delta_{S_3} + \Delta_{S_4}}{2\pi}$$
- $\epsilon(r) = \sqrt{8}r e^{-r} + e^{-2r}\;$ and $\;\eta(r) = \frac{r}{\cosh(r) + r}$.

One the line segment $S_1 = [-R_n-R_ni,+R_n-R_ni]$,

$$\sin z - z = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix+R_n} - e^{-ix-R_n}) - z
= \frac{e^{R_n+ix}}{2i}\left( 1 - 2i z e^{-(R_n+ix)} - e^{-2(R_n+ix)} \right)
$$

Notice $\displaystyle\;\left| 2i z e^{-(R_n+ix)} - e^{-2(R_n+ix)} \right| 
\le \epsilon(R_n) \le \epsilon(R_0) \approx 0.1198\;$ is always very small, we find
$$\left|\Delta_{S_1} - 2R_n\right| \le 2\sin^{-1}\epsilon(R_n)$$

By a similar argument, we have

$$\left|\Delta_{S_3} - 2R_n\right| \le 2\sin^{-1}\epsilon(R_n)$$

On the line segment $S_2 = [ +R_n - R_ni, +R_n + R_ni ]$,

$$\sin z - z = \sin R_n\cosh y + \cos R_n\sinh y\, i - (R_n + i y) = -( \cosh y + R_n ) + iy$$
Since the real part never change sign, we have
$$\left|\Delta_{S_2}\right| = 2\tan^{-1}\eta(R_n)$$
By a similar argument, we have

$$\left|\Delta_{S_4}\right| = 2\tan^{-1}\eta(R_n)$$

Above discussions implies

$$
\begin{align}
\left| \mathcal{W}_n - \frac{4R_n}{2\pi} \right| 
&\le \frac{2}{\pi}\left(\sin^{-1}\epsilon(R_n) + \tan^{-1}\eta(R_n)\right)\\
&\le \frac{2}{\pi}\left(\sin^{-1}\epsilon(R_0) + \tan^{-1}\eta(R_0)\right)\\
&\approx 0.126
\end{align}
$$

Since both $\mathcal{W}_n$ and $\frac{4R_n}{2\pi} = 4n+3$ are integers, we get $\mathcal{W}_n = 4n+3$.
Since $\sin z - z$ is entire, counting multiplicity, there are $4n+3$ roots of $(*1)$  inside $C_n$.
It is easy to see

- $z = 0$ is a triple root for $\sin z - z$.
- there are no other roots of $(*1)$ on the $x$ and $y$ axis.
- By symmetry, if $z = x + iy$ is a root, so does $\pm x \pm y i$.

As a result, all non-zero roots of $(*1)$ are simple. There are $4n+1$ distinct roots inside each $C_n$.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a fairly simple and geometrically intuitive argument based on the following fixed point theorem.

*Lemma*: Let $R \subset \mathbb C$ be a solid rectangle  and suppose that $f:R\rightarrow\mathbb C$ is continuous. If $f(R)\supset R$, then $f$ has a fixed point in $R$.

Note that the lemma holds for any compact, simply connected set. It's stated for solid rectangles to keep it as simple as possible.  By a "solid" rectangle, we mean that the interior is included.  The lemma is a consequence of Brower's fixed point theorem, though there's probably a much easier way to prove it.

Now, given a positive integer $n$, let $x_0=2n\pi+\pi/2$, let $y_0=\text{arccosh}(x_0)+1$ and let $R$ denote the rectangle
$$R = [x_0-\pi/2,x_0+\pi/2] \times [0,y_0].$$
It's fairly simple to parametrize the boundary of $R$ using the expansion
$$\sin(x+iy) = \sin (x) \cosh (y)+i \cos (x) \sinh (y).$$
In particular, given any fixed value of $y$, $\sin(x+iy)$ traces out the right half of an ellipse with semi-major axes of length $\cosh(y)$ and $\sinh(y)$. For large $y$, the ellipse is nearly a circle, since $\cosh(y)\approx\sinh(y)$, and the radius is quite large compared to the rectangle. The left and right sides of the rectangle map into the imaginary axis.  For $n=1$, the image looks like so:

[image]

As a result, that rectangle must contain a fixed point of the sine function.  Since this is true for each $n$, there are infinitely many fixed points.

---

We can also get more precise information on the location of the fixed points.  Here is a plot of the fixed point in the first quadrant with real part less than 100.

[image]

The curve is $z(t)=\cosh(t)+it$ and the fixed points appear to cluster on the curve.  We can see why this should be so by again examining the expansion of the complex sine function but this time restricted to the curve:
$$\sin (\cosh (t)+i t)=\cosh (t) \sin (\cosh (t))+i \sinh (t) \cos (\cosh (t)).$$

Now suppose that $t$ is chosen so that $\sinh(t)\cos(\cosh(t)) = t$, so that the sine function preserves the imaginary part. A graph should convince you that there are infinitely many such $t$.  Furthermore, since $\sinh(t)$ is so much larger than $t$, we must have that $\cos(\cosh(t)$ is very small so that $\cosh(t)\approx n\pi + \pi/2$.  In the case that $n$ is even, we get $\sin(\cosh (t))\approx 1$ so that the real part is *nearly* preserved as well.  Thus, we'd expect a fixed point nearby.

Answer (score 3):

A widely applicable and elementary approach based on Banach's fixed point theorem can be found [here](https://wimcouwenberg.wordpress.com/2014/08/18/fixed-points-of-entire-functions/).

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z) : = \sin z - z$, which if we let $z = x+iy$, we may write as $$f(z) = \frac{i}{2} \left( \exp(y-xi) - \exp(-y+xi) \right) - (x+iy).$$ For any fixed natural number $n$, choose a positive number $t$ significantly larger than $\log n$ and a closed contour $\Gamma = \Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2 \cup \Gamma_3 \cup \Gamma_4$ in the anticlockwise sense, where \begin{eqnarray*}
\Gamma_1 &=& \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : 2\pi n \leq x \leq 2(n+1)\pi, y=0 \}, \\
\Gamma_2 &=& \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : x = 2(n+1) \pi, 0 \leq y \leq t \}, \\
\Gamma_3 &=& \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : 2\pi n \leq x \leq 2(n+1) \pi, y =t \}, \\
\Gamma_4 &=& \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : 2\pi n, 0 \leq y \leq t \}. 
\end{eqnarray*} Then we consider the image of $\gamma$ under $f$. Indeed, we have \begin{eqnarray*}
f(\Gamma_1) &=& \{ w = u+iv : -2(n+1) \pi \leq u \leq -2\pi n, v =0 \}, \\
f(\Gamma_2) &=& \{ w = u+iv : u= -2(n+1) \pi, 0 \leq v \leq \frac{1}{2}(e^t - e^{-t}) -t \}, \\
f(\Gamma_3) &=& \left \{ w : \frac{1}{2} e^t - \left( \frac{1}{2} e^{-t} + t + 2(n+1) \pi \right) \leq \left| w \right| \leq \frac{1}{2}e^t + \left( \frac{1}{2} e^{-t} + t +2(n+1) \pi \right) \right \}, \\
f(\Gamma_4 )&=& \{ w : u = -2\pi n, 0 \leq v \leq \frac{1}{2} (e^t - e^{-t} ) -t \}. 
\end{eqnarray*} So the winding number of $f(\Gamma)$ around $w=0$ is $1$. By the argument principle, $f(z) = \sin z - z$ has one zero inside the contour $\Gamma$. Since $n$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $\sin z = z$ has infinitely many solutions.