# Solve $\sin z = z$ for $|z|\leq1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, for which $|z| ≤ 1$ and
$\sin z = z$. Here I put $z=0$. Please someone who correct me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117973/does-sinxiy-xiy-have-infinitely-many-solutions