# Values of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find out if the $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z}$ takes all the values in complex plain.

I think I need somehow to apply Picard’s theorem but I don’t know how.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ surely has infinitely many zeros. For $a \ne 0$ we are looking for zeros of $g(z) = f(z) - az$, and you can argue similarly as in [Does $\sin(x+iy) = x+iy$ have infinitely many solutions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117973/does-sinxiy-xiy-have-infinitely-many-solutions/1118093#1118093): The Great Picard theorem implies that (at least) one of

- $g(z)$
- $g(z)-2\pi a = g(z+2\pi)$

must have infinitely many zeros.